# Using chop in grep expression

Tags: perl, chop

My Perl script searches a directory of file names, using **grep** to output only file names without the numbers 2-9 in their names. That means, as intended, that file names ending with the number "1" will also be returned. However, I want to use the **chop** function to output these file names without the "1", but can't figure out how. Perhaps the **grep** and **chop** functions can be combined in one line of code to achieve this? Please advise. Thanks.

Here's my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';
opendir(DIR, $dir);
@files = grep (/^[^2-9]*\.png\z/,readdir(DIR));

foreach $file (@files) {
   print "$file\n";
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Ilex_verticillata.png
Asarum_canadense1.png
Ageratina_altissima.png
Lonicera_maackii.png
Chelone_obliqua1.png
```

Here's my desired output with the number "1" removed from the end of file names:

```
Ilex_verticillata.png
Asarum_canadense.png
Ageratina_altissima.png
Lonicera_maackii.png
Chelone_obliqua.png
```

Comment: Tip: You should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Tip: Unecessarily using global vars is a bad practice. Replace `opendir(DIR, $dir)` with `opendir(my $DIR, $dir)` (and replace later instances of `DIR` with `$DIR`).

Comment: Tip: `opendir` is very likely to fail. It's best to have at least some minimal error checking. (`opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die("Can't open directory \"$dir\": $!\n");`)

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Should the error checking code be incorporated into the code like this:  opendir(my $DIR, $dir); (opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die("Can't open directory \"$dir\": $!\n");) –

Comment: @Jeff  I show that in my answer (yes)

Comment: I am confused now.  The question implies, in my mind, that you want the `1` removed only when it's at the end of the filename. Is that so?  Or do you want it removed from everywhere in the filename?  (Then why not filter out 1-9?)

Comment: I want to find file names with the number "1" at the end of their names, but I want those file names to be outputted without that "1". For example, I want the find "Asarum_candense1" in the directory, but I want it outputted as "Asarum_candense" without the "1" at the end of the file name. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Alright, that's what I thought.  But what about possible `1` in the middle of the name?  Say, `hi1_no1.png` --- should this become `hi1_no.png` (with the first `1` kept) or `hi_no.png` (both `1`s removed) ?

Comment: (I goofed up with that "_why not filter out 1-9_" -- that's not what you want of course)

Comment: I only want to remove the number "1" from the end of file names, and the map/grep expression you provided does that perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number `1` to remove is at the end of the name before the extension; this is different from filtering on numbers (2-9) altogether and I wouldn't try to fit it into one operation.

Instead, once you have your filtered list (no 2-9 in names), then clip off that `1`. Seeing that all names of interest are `.png` can simply use a regex

```
$filename =~ s/1\.png\z/.png/;
```

and if there is no `1` right before `.png` the string is unchanged. If it were possible to have other extensions involved then you should use a module to break up the filename.

To incorporate this, you can pass `grep`'s output through a `map`

```
opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $!";

my @files = 
    map { s/1\.png\z/.png/r } 
    grep { /^[^2-9]*\.png\z/ } 
    readdir $dfh;
```

where I've also introduced a lexical directory filehandle instead of a glob, and added a check on whether `opendir` worked.  The `/r` modifier on the substitution in `map` is needed so that the string is returned (changed or unchanged if regex didn't match), and not changed in place, as needed here.

This passes over the list of filenames twice, though, while one can use a straight loop. In principle that may impact performance; however, here all operations are done on each element of a list so a difference in performance is minimal.

Comment: Re "*This passes over the list of filenames twice, though. [...] that may impact performance*", Doing two loops that do one thing each is not meaningfully slower than doing one loop that does two things.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, zdim! You guys make it look easy!!!

Comment: @ikegami Since each operation is done on every element there's indeed not much of a difference. Adjusted text, thank you

Answer (score 5):

You could use use the following:

```perl
s/1//g for @files;
```

It's also possible to integrate a solution into your chain using `map`.

```perl
my @files =
   map s/1//rg,
      grep /^[^2-9]*\.png\z/,
         readdir(DIR);
```

Comment: Wow... the "map" expression works!!! I don't understand how, but it does! Thank you!!!

Comment: From what the OP says it appears that they want `1` removed only when it's at the end of the filename, right before extension?  They don't exclude the case where there may be more `1`s in the filename (and that seems possible since they first filter on 2-9 only)

Comment: `map` takes an expression and a list of scalars like `grep`. It applies a transformation to each of those scalars.

Comment: @zdim, Probably, but then `^[^2-9]*` is probably "wrong" too. So I stuck with what they said rather than creating an inconsistency.